# Adobe Flash Error creating flash movie file Destination directory doesn't exist

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3

I am working through an audio player demonstration in the book "Foundation Actionscript 3.0".  When I try to publish my AudioDemo_final.FLA file I get the following error, "Adobe Flash CS3 - Error creating flash movie file. Destination directory does not exist. Change your publish settings."

The following is displayed in my output panel >> Error opening URL 'file:///C|/Sites/flashcoder.net/FAS3/Audio/AudioDemo%5Ffinal.swf'

My file directory is set up like this:
AudioDemo_final.fla
song1.mp3
com.fas3.smc (folder)
        Main.as
        Sounds.as

```
    //com.fas3.smc/Main.as
    package com.fas3.smc {
            import flash.display.MovieClip;
            import com.fas3.smc.Sounds;
            import com.fas3.smc.ButtonManager;
            import flash.text.TextField;
            import flash.display.SimpleButton;

            public class Main extends MovieClip {
                    private var soundManager:Sounds;
                    private var buts:ButtonManager;

                    public function Main() {
                            soundManager=new Sounds(movScrubber, txtStatus, txtHeadPosition, txtTrackLength, txtArtist, txtTitle, volumeSlider, panSlider);
                            soundManager.loadSong(    song1.mp3    );
                            addChild(soundManager);
                    }
            }
    }

    //com.fas3.smc/Sounds.as
    package com.fas3.smc {
            import flash.media.Sound;
            import flash.media.SoundChannel;
            import flash.media.SoundLoaderContext;
            import flash.media.SoundTransform;
            import flash.media.ID3Info;
            import flash.events.Event;
            import flash.display.MovieClip;
            import flash.net.URLRequest;
            import flash.text.TextField;
            import flash.utils.Timer;
            import flash.events.TimerEvent;
            import fl.controls.Slider;
            import fl.events.SliderEvent;

            public class Sounds extends MovieClip {
                    private var snd1:Sound;
                    private var sc:SoundChannel;
                    private var buffer:SoundLoaderContext;
                    private var timerLoading:Timer;
                    private var timerPlayHead:Timer;
                    private var timerFF:Timer;
                    private var timerRW:Timer;
                    private var timerSpectrum:Timer;
                    private var barWid:int = 200;
                    private var barHi:int = 5;
                    private var bytLoaded:int;
                    private var bytTotal:int;
                    private var pctLoaded:int;
                    private var trueChronoLength:Number;
                    private var txtStatus:TextField;
                    private var txtTrackLength:TextField;
                    private var txtHeadPosition:TextField;
                    private var txtArtist:TextField;
                    private var txtTitle:TextField;
                    private var movScreen:MovieClip;
                    private var movScrubber:MovieClip;
                    private var multiplier:Number;
                    private var nsMinutes:Number;
                    private var nsSeconds:Number;
                    private var pauseStatus:Boolean;
                    private var playHeadPosition:Number;
                    private var volumeSlider:Slider;
                    private var panSlider:Slider;
                    private var stVolume:SoundTransform;
                    private var tempVol:Number=0.5;
                    private var tempPan:Number=0;
                    private var trackEnd:Boolean;
                    private var trackStart:Boolean;

                    public function Sounds(movScrubber:MovieClip, txtStatus:TextField, txtHeadPosition:TextField, txtTrackLength:TextField, txtArtist:TextField, txtTitle:TextField, volumeSlider:Slider, panSlider:Slider) {
                            //Set movies and text fields to local references and to start positions and contents
                            this.movScreen=movScreen;
                            this.movScrubber=movScrubber;
                            this.txtStatus=txtStatus;
                            this.txtHeadPosition=txtHeadPosition;
                            this.txtTrackLength=txtTrackLength;
                            this.txtArtist=txtArtist;
                            this.txtTitle=txtTitle;
                            this.volumeSlider=volumeSlider;
                            this.panSlider=panSlider;
                            timerLoading=new Timer(100, 0);
                            timerLoading.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onLoading);
                            timerLoading.start();

                    }

                    public function loadSong(song:String):void {
                            snd1=new Sound(new URLRequest(song))
                            snd1.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler)
                    }

                    public function onLoading(event.TimerEvent):void {
                            bytLoaded = snd1.bytesLoaded;
                            bytTotal = snd1.bytesTotal;
                            if((bytTotal >= bytLoaded)&&(bytLoaded > 0)) {
                                    if(txtStatus.text!=    Playing    ) {
                                            txtStatus.text=    Loading    ;
                                    }
                                    movScrubber.movLoaderBar.width=((bytLoaded/bytTotal) * 400);
                                    if(bytLoaded == bytTotal) {
                                            if(txtStatus.text=    Loading    ) {
                                                    txtStatus.text=    Load Complete    ;
                                            }
                                            timerLoading.stop()
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that the directory that you're publishing your SWF to isn't writeable, or doesn't exist. Check to see that the folder path indeed does exist and that it's able to be written to. Many times, if I move a project to a different location, but have the publish path hard-coded in my FLA, it'll throw this error. It's in File->Publish Settings->Formats.

Comment: what do you have in there for the path? It seems like this isn't a valid file path at first glance - what's the | in there?: 'file:///C|/Sites/flashcoder.net/FAS3/Audio/AudioDemo%5Ffinal.swf'

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an external hardrive? I had the same issue once. Copy the FLA File to the desktop or to a local folder and that should solve it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Check the folder in which you are saving this file, if that folder has the readonly permissions than you will get this error and if you remove the readonly permissions everything will work as expected.
I tried that and it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late for the post, but I had the same problem. The problem popped up because I actually clicked the browse button and selected the folder for publishing.

Instead of browsing, just click "default". The files will be published to the same directory as your .fla file. No more weird error messages.